# Including Random Slopes for Variables That Are Not Specified as Fixed Effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-variable, fixed-effects-model

I am interested in whether it is ever logical to specify a random slope of a variable that is not listed as a fixed effect in the model. For clarity, I have provided an example below.

10 Participants complete a reaction time (RT) task identifying whether a sentence makes sense or not. Sentences are from two conditions (Condition A and Condition B). There are 10 different sentences used, with each sentence appearing twice (once in each condition). All participants see the same sentences.

For clarity, here is a sample of this dataset:

| Participant | Sentence | Condition | RT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 0.01 |
| 1 | 1 | B | 0.05 |
| 1 | 2 | B | 0.07 |
| 1 | 2 | A | 0.10 |
| 2 | 9 | A | 0.05 |
| 2 | 9 | B | 0.08 |

The first mixed model examines the effect of `Condition` and `Sentence`, with a random effect of `Participant` and by-`Participant` slopes for `Condition`, `Sentence`, and the interaction between these variables.

```
model_1<-lmer(RT ~ Condition*Sentence+(Condition * Sentence|Participant))
```

The second mixed model uses only `Condition` as a fixed effect, but the random effect structure remains the same. While in theory it would seem possible here to investigate how the effect of `Sentence` varies across participants, I am unsure whether this is possible in a mixed model if `Sentence` is not specified as a fixed effect.

```
model_2<-lmer(RT ~ Condition+(Condition * Sentence|Participant))
```

I realise that all models require selection of the most appropriate model based on the experimental question, theory, and model fitting. I also realise that there are other ways to include `Sentence` as a random effect, such as with random intercepts for `Sentence`.This question therefore does not relate to which is the better model and/or whether there are other ways to include `Sentence` in the model, but asks whether it is ever possible (based on the mathematics/logic of the mixed model) to include a random effect for a variable that is not listed as a fixed effect.